# WIFI Module can't get the data from the server

Tags: embedded, esp8266, esp8266wifi

I am trying to connect the esp 8266 wifi module with the online server when I press a button on the site I expect to see the data in the file.txt that I upload to the site but I receive something like this brief in the image

i tried many times but every time when i get that the module connected to the wifi and got the ip afte that i type the at command

AT+CIPSTART="TCP","23.179.32.37",80

AT+CIPSEND=64

GET http://iotarmonline.freevar.com/file.txt

the module responded with busy s.... and close the connection
or it tells me that 400 error and tell me this request is bad request

Comment: `GET url` is not the correct http format, read [HTTP Overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview#http_flow) to get better understanding on how http protocol work.

Comment: why is that wrong i think it is an error from the server itself due to i get 302 found error